# Debugging over wifi an app that is connected to a specific USB controller

Tags: android, usb, adb, android-tv, xiaomi

I am currently developping an app that will connect to a specific USB controller for Xiaomi Mi box S.

The problem is, the Mi box have only one USB port so I am using adb over wifi to debug it and still have my USB port available for my custom USB thingy. I am able to connect to my Mi box through adb over wifi when I enable USB debbuging but then, the USB port does not behave like a host anymore and it does not detect anymore my USB controller.

How can I get my Mi box to accept adb over wifi with my USB port behaving as usual ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have the answe for you but also have a question

Answer

1) connect the device via USB
2) type: adb tcpip 5555
3) get the devioce IP address. you can get this in the device settings / about phone/status
4) type: adb connect [IP address]:5555

you will the be able to connect via WIFI in android studio.

My question is.

I was able to do this in Windows 10. but rather develop in Linux/Ubuntu. I cannot get the system to see the MI Box s device. I have done this sucessfully with phones and other TV boxes but not with the MI box

Thanks